# How to add the "src" dynamically and start/stop playing

Tags: javascript, html, media-player

```
<EMBED  id = "player"
                        TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" 
                        NAME="MediaPlayer" 
                        WIDTH="192" 
                        HEIGHT="190" 
                        ShowControls="1" 
                        ShowStatusBar="0" 
                        ShowDisplay="0" 
                        autostart="0"> 
</EMBED>
```

I tried

```
document.getElementById("player").src = "http://localhost/abc/test.wmv";
```

it does not work

what should i do?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest moving to HTML 5 `<audio>` with a Flash fallback instead of this non-standard legacy from the 3.x browser era.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the `setAttribute` method like this...

```
document.getElementById("player").setAttribute("src", "http://localhost/abc/test.wmv");
```

Comment: when i check it from firebug the attribute is finely seted. But its not playing. Even the play button is not working

Comment: @dinesh707; Not sure about playing it. There must be a way to "reload" the content, but I have not done that part before

Comment: @dinesh707: maybe [this](http://www.protofunc.com/2008/02/01/controlling-embedded-video-with-javascript-part-i-quicktime/) might be of use?

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery. There is a FlashEmbed tool that makes it easy to do so.

http://jquery.com/
http://flowplayer.org/tools/toolbox/flashembed.html

Comment: could someone tell me why I'm downvoted? Is this answer so wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in jquery it should be

```
$('#player').attr('src','http://localhost/abc/test.wmv');
```

in pure js i think

```
document.getElementById('player').setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost/abc/test.wmv');
```